# Flutter x Woocomerce Rest API App: Filtering products using Size and Color

Tags: wordpress, flutter, woocommerce

I have a flutter app I am building using my Woocomerce REST as a backend. When i fetch products i get a response like:

[
{ name: ""
...

```
     attributes": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Colour",
            "position": 0,
            "visible": true,
            "variation": false,
            "options": [
                "Navy/White"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Size",
            "position": 1,
            "visible": true,
            "variation": true,
            "options": [
                "S",
                "M",
                "L",
                "XL"
            ]
        }

    ],},
```

{...}]

I want to be able to filter products by the attributes and I know how to do that, I have to pass the id,but from this response the id of the term is not listed and using the attributes/terms endpoint to display all colors is going to be bad UX since there are at least 70 and it will make it hard for users to filter accurately.

So i mapped through and extracted each value of color and size I could find and displayed that for them to chose, but this means filtering would be done on the Client side , which upon scroll might re-arrange the ui.

I was wondering if there was a better method to this. Seems a bit advanced but any help is appreciated!